# Transforming boundary value problem to initia value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation, dynamical-systems

Consider the following boundary value problem on the interval $[a,b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ :

$$ \ddot x = f(t,x,\dot x), ~~~ x = x(t) \\
\alpha = a_0 x(a) - a_1 \dot x(a), ~~ \vert a_0 \vert + \vert a_1\vert \neq 0 \\
\beta = b_0 x(b) - b_1 \dot x(b), ~~ \vert b_0 \vert + \vert b_1\vert \neq 0 $$

with $\alpha, \beta, a_0, a_1, b_0, b_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ given.

We want to analyze it as an initial value problem. For this, we consider the IVP (S1)

$$ \ddot u = f(t,u,\dot u), ~~~ u = u(t) \\
\alpha = a_0 u(a) - a_1 \dot u(a), ~~ \vert a_0 \vert + \vert a_1\vert \neq 0 \\
s = c_0 u(a) - c_1 \dot u(a), ~~ \vert c_0 \vert + \vert c_1\vert \neq 0 \\
a_0 c_1 - c_0 a_1 = 1$$

with $\alpha, a_0, a_1, c_0, c_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ given and $s \in \mathbb{R}$ a free parameter. Write the solutions to this problem $u(t;s)$. We want to vary $s$ and hope that when

$$b_0 u(b;s_*) + b_1 \dot u(b,s_*) - \beta = 0 ~~~~~ (1)$$

then $u(t,s_*) =: x(t)$ is a solution to the boundary value problem.

Now my textbook does this as follows, which is where I am confused:

Firstly, they write the IVP as a system of first order (S2) as

$$ \dot u = f(t,u,v) \\
\dot v = u \\
\begin{pmatrix} -c_1 & c_0 \\
-a_1 & a_0 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\
s \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} u(a) \\ 
v(a) \end{pmatrix} $$

Then we want to show that the solutions to the BVP are $x(t) = u(t,s_*)$ where $s_*$ is a solution to equation $(1)$.

I do not understand why these two systems are equivalent, and why the solutions are $u(t,

My main two points of confusion are:

1. It seems what is the function $u$ in (S1) is $v$ in (S2). So why would the solutions $x$ be $u(-,s_*)$ and not $v(-,s_*)$?
2. The last condition in (S1) says that the two first order conditions are linearly independent i.e. we may write the two conditions as

$$\begin{pmatrix} a_0 & -a_1 \\
c_0 & -c_1 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} u(a) \\
\dot u(a) \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ 
s \end{pmatrix} $$

Then the last condition of (S1) says that the determinant is $-1$. Now if we want to translate that to (S2) this gives

$$- \begin{pmatrix} -c_1 & a_1  \\
- c_0 & a_0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\
s \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} u(a) \\ 
v(a) \end{pmatrix} $$

However, this does not coincide with what is written in (S2).

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems strange that the right boundary equation is drawn to the left side. The linear independence there has no influence on the solvability and local uniqueness of the BVP solution. It could make sense if a homotopy method were employed that would increase the right interval bound step-by-step from $a$ to $b$, but that seems not to be the case. I would simply set $v(a)=s$ and thus $u(a)=(α+a_1s)/a_0$, where then $f(s)=β-c_0u(b)+c_1v(b)$ is a rather arbitrary function of $s$.

Comment: That's my bad - edited. Does it make more sense now? We introduce another condition on the left boundary and vary the parameter accordingly to get a solution to the right boundary condition.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. It avoids the problems with the case $a_0=0$ or similar with other parametrizations of the initial condition without citing these corner cases.

Comment: Could you explain 1.) further, I do not see your interpretation. The introduction of $u$ in (S1) is not really necessary, I do not see what the difference to the formulation with $x$ is. In (S2) it is clearly $x=u$, $\dot x=\dot u=v$. And yes, as to 2.), there is an exponent $-1$ for the matrix inverse missing, or the correct form of the matrix inverse.

Comment: 1) I do not see how S1 as S2. The purpose seems to be to make S1 into a system of order 1. But in S1, $u$ is a function satisfying that the *second* derivative is equal to $f(t,u,\dot u)$. But then in S2, $u$ is some function satisfying the it's first derivative equals $f(t,u,v)$ and $\dot v = u$. How can that describe the same function? I would guess S2 should be something like $\dot u = v, \dot v = f(t,u, \dot v)$. Then again, $u$ is a function s.t. it's second derivative equals $f(...)$

Comment: Insidious. You are right, (S2) has multiple errors. The correct order-one system is of course $\dot v=f(t,u,v)$, $\dot u=v$ and the corrected solution of the linear system for the initial conditions.